# Operator syntax for Merge-like Query

Tags: bugs, dataset

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Is it possible to take advantage of Dataset's Query operator syntax to Merge parallel queries thereby avoiding Function's that are otherwise required?

Using the planets data:

```
 planets = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];

{moonMasses, nMoons } = {planets[All, "Moons", Median, "Mass"], 
  planets[All, "Moons", Length, "Mass"]}
```

[image]

These queries are nearly equivalent merges:

(1) `Merge[{moonMasses // Normal, nMoons // Normal}, List]`

[image]

(2) `planets[All, "Moons", {Median[#], Length[#]} &, "Mass"] // Normal`

[image]

The values in (1) are unfortunately wrapped in an extra nested list (and further requres normalizing the data as Merge doesn't take `Dataset` arguments).

(2) is preferred (normalizing here only because 10.0.0 `Dataset Format` is not usable).

How to avoid using `Function` in (2), eg, to shorten the query to a syntax similar to:

```
planets[All, "Moons", {Median, Length}, "Mass"]
```

Comment: Am I wrong to understand from the documentation that your proposed short query syntax should work?

Comment: In the meantime, a subquery seems to work `planets[All, "Moons", Query[{Median, Length}], "Mass"]`

Comment: @Rojo, that works - I had tried `{Query[Median],Query[Length]}` but didn't think of this variation. Write it up as an answer, will accept.

Comment: This bug is not yet fixed in *Mathematica* 10.0.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Seems to be fixed in 10.0.2

Comment: @Gordon Confirmed and marked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Am I wrong to understand from the documentation that your proposed short query syntax should work?

In the meantime, a subquery seems to work `planets[All, "Moons", Query[{Median, Length}], "Mass"]`

Comment: `planets[All, "Moons", {Median, Length}, "Mass"]` should work, because `Median` and `Length` on their own are ascending, so `{Median, Length}` should clearly also be considered to be ascending. Thanks for finding!

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon are `Apply`, or `MapIndexed` given some special treatment (such as descending operators)? Because I usually find issues  with them but they aren't descending

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for Map to be descending, because `Map[f]` is really `All, f`. `Apply` *could* be descending, but it's more useful for it be ascending, because it is a useful sugar on top of other ascending functions, e.g. `Apply[#1 + #2&] <=> #[[1]] + #[[2]]&`. Not sure about MapIndexed.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon, makes sense, thx. So for example the fact that this doesn't work `Dataset[{1}][Apply[f]]` but this does `Dataset[{1}][Apply[f, #] &]` is a simple bug

Comment: yes, that's a bug. thanks, fixed!